# How can I get the relative object from the memory address?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, memory-management

I got the memory address error code from the debugger:

0x4dc1d00, how can I find out that memory address is relative to which class/attribute? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your question doesn't make much sense.

In what context do you get the address `0x4dc1d00` from the debugger?

An address is just that; an address in memory.  There may be any number of reasons why that address barfs up in the debugger.  If it is an allocation, there are tools for gleaning some more details.

However, an address is also just a number.  If you are looking for where that number might have ever appeared in the rest of your app, that is a question whose answer is often unknowable.

So.... what are you trying to do?